# Correct way to do Ledger system in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, currency, finance, accounting

So we are trying to work out in what format do we store money values in MongoDB we are talking dealing with cents.

For example if someone gets charged 0.04 but we take 30% commission we should get 0.012

But I am sure that we should not be storing data like $0.012 or even in 0.012

because technically you could end up with 0.0125 for example.

I read that you should use something like this. `trans_amount |   decimal |   10  |  Deposit amount`

Meaning in MongoDB it would be stored like:

```
{
trans_amount: NumberInit(00125)
}
```

However the issue is that if $10 was spend it would be store like

```
{
trans_amount: NumberInit(01000)
}
```

Now if we go back to the first above example and try to code it out we would get $1.25 instead of the $0.0125 it should be.

Now I am guessing the correct way would be to have 12 digits?

`000000000000`

However this works up to when you have a customer that wants to spend Trillion dollars at once (not that that would happen - but you never know)

So before I go and code a transaction database I want to work out the correct way to store cents and dollars in MongoDB for accounting.

According to Mongodb they recommend the following:

```
{
  price: { display: "9.99", approx: 9.9900000000000002, currency: "USD" },
  fee: { display: "0.25", approx: 0.2499999999999999, currency: "USD" }
}
```

OR

```
{ price: 9990, currency: "USD" }
```

However does `approx` automatically get done by MongoDB - My guess is no and I would have to work that out myself.

Comment: Why would it store like that? You can store 0.0125 as decimal. What's the difficulty in doing so.

Comment: @Gibbs how many decimals back can we go? I am just trying to make sure that we allow for other currencies down the track.

Comment: @Gibbs just did a quick currency convert and found that - 0.0125 AUD works out to be   0.00023 Chiean Unit Of Account (UF)

Would that not create a problem - unless we are storing the currency the amount is in?

At the start we will only allow AUD but we looking at rolling out support for all currencies in 3 years.

Comment: [Refer this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/#using-a-scale-factor) , it will clarify

Comment: @Gibbs - they say to store it like { price: 9990, currency: "USD" } But then go on to say {
  price: { display: "9.99", approx: 9.9900000000000002, currency: "USD" },
  fee: { display: "0.25", approx: 0.2499999999999999, currency: "USD" }
}

Comment: [Decimal128](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/bson-data-types-decimal128/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this:

```
{ price: 9990, currency: "USD" } //See it is not string
```

As in the above example, you can store. Here the thing is that number of decimals is fixed at any point of time.

The scale factor is consistent for a currency; i.e. same scaling factor for a given currency. The scale factor is a constant and known property of the currency; i.e applications can determine the scale factor from the currency.

In another way, you can use other type:

```
{
  price: { display: "9.99", approx: 9.9900000000000002, currency: "USD" },
  fee: { display: "0.25", approx: 0.2499999999999999, currency: "USD" }
}
```

Here, approx describes exact decimal value with more decimal. The value you query is represented by `display` field.

In one field, encode the exact monetary value as a non-numeric data type; e.g., BinData or a string. In the second field, store a double-precision floating point approximation of the exact value.

Comment: Should I be storing the current currency price for example USD?

Comment: One other question, so say we an account has $100 in it and we payout that $100 we would need a wallet or an account that that 100 gets transferred too to make it $0.00

Comment: Current currency price depends on your need. I didn't understand your second question.